# error on line 1 at column 3: xmlParsePI : no target name

Tags: php, html, xml

I need to generate a dynamic xml for the cms, products, images and categories pages of my online store. Here I show you the 3 files I use. The first one is the file funciones.php:

```
<?php
function devolver_url ($v,$i,$tipo=1)
   {
   foreach ($v as $linea)
     {
     $b=explode ("#",$linea);
     if ($b[1]==$i)
       $retorno=$b[2];
     }
  return $retorno;
 }
function devolver_url_productos ($v,$i)
   {
   foreach ($v as $linea)
    {
    $b=explode ("#",$linea); 
    if ($b[1]==$i)
      $retorno=$b[2]."/".$b[4]."-".$b[3].".html";
    }
 return $retorno;
 }
function consultar_bd($consulta)
   {
   $bd="XXXXXXX"; 
   $clave="XXXXXXXXX";
   $host="localhost:3306";
   $conexion = mysql_connect($host, $user, $clave);
   mysql_select_db($bd, $conexion);
   $resultado = mysql_query($consulta, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
   return $resultado;
   }

function quitar_tildes($cadena)
{
$no_permitidas= array ("á","é","í","ó","ú","Á","É","Í","Ó","Ú","ñ","À","Ã","Ì","Ò","Ù","Ã™","Ã ","Ã¨","Ã¬","Ã²","Ã¹","ç","Ç","Ã¢","ê","Ã®","Ã´","Ã»","Ã‚","ÃŠ","ÃŽ","Ã”","Ã›","ü","Ã¶","Ã–","Ã¯","Ã¤","«","Ò","Ã","Ã„","Ã‹");
$permitidas= array ("a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U","n","N","A","E","I","O","U","a","e","i","o","u","c","C","a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U","u","o","O","i","a","e","U","I","A","E");
$texto = str_replace($no_permitidas, $permitidas ,$cadena);
return $texto;
}?>
```

File funciones_cms.php :

```
<?php
    include ("funciones.php");
    function poner_url_cms ($v)
       {
       $dominio="https://www.mobiliariocomercialmaniquies.com/";
       $l=array("nada","en","fr","es","de","it","ca");
       foreach ($v as $a)
          {
          $b=explode ("#",$a);
          echo '
                <url>
                <loc>'.$dominio.$l[$b[1]].'/content/'.$b[0].'-'.$b[2].'</loc>
                ';
          for ($i=1;$i<7;$i++)
             {
             if ($i<>$b[1])
                {
                echo '<xhtml:link 
                rel="alternate"
                ';
                echo 'hreflang="'.$l[$i].'"
                ';
                echo 'href="'.$dominio.$l[$i].'/content/'.$b[0].'-'.devolver_url($v,$i,1).'"
                />';
                }
             }            
            echo '</url>
            '; 
          }
       } 
    function generar_sitemap()
       {
       $consulta= "SELECT id_lang, id_cms,link_rewrite FROM ps_cms_lang";
       $resultado = consultar_bd($consulta);
       $filas = mysql_num_rows($resultado);
       $cms=0;
       if ($filas > 0) 
       {
       while ($r= mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) 
       {  
          if ( ($r['link_rewrite']<>"") && ($r['id_lang']<7) ) 
             {
               if ($r['id_cms']==$cms)
                   {
                   $v[]=$cms."#".$r['id_lang']."#".$r['link_rewrite'];
                   }
               else
                   {
                   if ($cms==0)
                      {
                      unset($v);
                      $cms=$r['id_cms'];
                      $v[0]=$cms."#".$r['id_lang']."#".$r['link_rewrite'];
                      }         
                   else
                      {
                      poner_url_cms($v);
                      unset($v);
                      $cms=$r['id_cms'];
                      $v[0]=$cms."#".$r['id_lang']."#".$r['link_rewrite'];
                      }
                   }
             }  
          }
       poner_url_cms($v);   
       }
    }
    ?>
```

And finally i need to make the file cms.xml but it does not work:

```
    <? 
    header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    include ("../funciones/funciones_cms.php");
    include ("../funciones/funciones.php");
    ?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <?php echo generar_sitemap() ?>
    </urlset>
```

I need to generate a dynamic xml for the cms, products, images and categories pages of my online store. Could you help me please?

Comment: You would be much better learning how to use SimpleXML than trying to create your own XML generator.

Comment: Ohhh! thank you very much for your answer...I thought that same thing I was trying to do by posting my question here

Answer (score 0):

1. Your 'cms.xml' is not parsed by the webserver as PHP
2. The HTTP client recieves the PHP source
3. The PHP source is not valid XML
4. The XML parser in the client throws an error

If you name the file `cms.xml` the webserver will not execute it as PHP (at least not without special configuration). That means that the PHP source will be send to the HTTP client. This includes the `<?` that starts your PHP source at the top of the file.

`<?` in XML is used for [processing instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction) (short PI), but they require a target name like `<?xml-stylesheet ...?>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your response.

So, how can I show that PHP file that the sitemap generates without it being HTML? since google search console does not allow a sitemap like html.